# using curl and storing cookie as a variable

Tags: php, variables, curl

i have a curl function that visits a website, logs in to said website, stores the cookie file, then can later read the cookie file to visit a page that would normally require a login.

problem i am faced with is i want to save and retrieve the cookie file using a php variable but cant seem to get it to work.

```
$username = "myusername";
function getUrl($url, $method='', $vars='') {
$ch = curl_init();
if ($method == 'post') {
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $vars);
}
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookies/$username.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookies/$username.txt");
$buffer = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $buffer;
}
```

i assume the syntax is wrong, and not that curl cant handle a variable as a location?

Comment: Do `cookies/` exist? Is it writable by the web server user?

Comment: yes and yes. i know because if i name it anything at all (that isnt a variable) even if the .txt file doesnt exist, it creates it. which essentially is what i aim to have except using variables instead of hard coded text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the scope of the `$username` variable. Because it's outside the function, it's not available inside the function. You should either add the username as a parameter of the function or use the `global` keyword so that it's accessible inside the function.

See https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php for more information.

Comment: thank you! global $username; inside the function fixed my problem!